# Using Lambdas to create and populate objects as an argument

Tags: java, methods, lambda, parameters, arguments

I find Java lambda syntax to be uniquely obscure and confusing, compared to other languages' more straightforward lambdas...

My understanding is that you can pass a lambda in lieu of an object as a parameter of a method, and the syntax goes something like

```
method(() -> { /*code to return value*/ } )
```

But I can't get a syntax that will work.

I want to build a list of objects, and I want to populate each new object with unique data (let's say a Math.random() value). So I'm trying to do this:

```
ArrayList<MyType> mytypes = new ArrayList<>();
mytypes.add( () -> { MyType m = new MyType(); m.populate(Math.random()); return m } );
```

But that apparently isn't legit, although it seems to match what minimal examples there are out there for doing this. I've also tried

```
mytypes.add( t -> { MyType m = new MyType(); m.populate(Math.random()); return m } );

mytypes.add( MyType t -> { MyType m = new MyType(); m.populate(Math.random()); return m } );

mytypes.add( (MyType t) -> { MyType m = new MyType(); m.populate(Math.random()); return m } );

mytypes.add( { MyType m = new MyType(); m.populate(Math.random()); return m } );
```

based on various syntaxes seen online, which have been barely informative.

So what is wrong with any of this? How to do this? Is it just not possible? (Shame, because most other languages using lambdas would seem to do it intuitively.)

Comment: "My understanding is that you can pass a lambda in lieu of an object as a parameter of a method" Nope...

Comment: You keep saying "other languages" and seem to claim that you understand lambdas in these other languages. Can you give an example? Because I don't know any language where you can "pass a lambda in lieu of an object"...

Comment: @Sweeper you can pass a lambda as an object to method that accepts a parameter of type `Object` if you cast it as a `FunctionalInterface`, eg `(Function)x -> x`. Probably doesn't count, but just saying.

Comment: @Bohemian I was confused for a second there, before your comment edit...

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas can only be used where an instance of a functional interface is expected. A functional interface is an interface with a single abstract method. The lambda gets compiled into an instance implementing that interface, and the lambda body becomes the implementation of that single interface method.

Here:

```
ArrayList<MyType> mytypes = new ArrayList<>();
mytypes.add( () -> { MyType m = new MyType(); m.populate(Math.random()); return m } );
```

No overload of `add` takes a functional interface as a parameter. Hence the above does not compile. It should instead be written as separate statements:

```
ArrayList<MyType> mytypes = new ArrayList<>();
MyType m = new MyType();
m.populate(Math.random());
mytypes.add(m);
```

For completeness' sake, you can technically write it using a lambda with a trick, by casting the lambda to a `Supplier<MyType>`, which *is* a functional interface, and then call `get` to actually run the code in the lambda.

```
mytypes.add( ((Supplier<MyType>)(() -> { MyType m = new MyType(); m.populate(Math.random()); return m })).get() );
```

**But please don't write code like this...** I don't know what "other languages" in which this is acceptable, but this is not how we do it in *Java*.

Comment: I like your last sentence the best.